# Setting variable using datas retrieved by Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve data from an Asynchronous function of Firebase and then set it as the ViewController's user variable:

```
    var user : User!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    fetchUser()
}


func fetchUser(){

    Api.User.observeCurrentUser { (user) in
        self.user = user

    }
```

The problem is that within the brackets of the 'observeCurrentUser' method I can actually see the user retrieved correctly but outside them the it is not associated to the self.user and when I try to print it outside the brackets it's nil.

Being said this, I searched on the web and I found out that this is because it's an asynchronous function. 
How can I get the self.user equal to the user retrieved in the 'observeCurrentUser' function so that I can work on it in the ViewController?

The Api.User.observeCurrentUser function retrieves the currentUser. 
It's coded in this way:

```
func observeCurrentUser(completion: @escaping (User)-> Void){

    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return
    }

    REF_USERS.child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
            let user = User.transformUser(dict: dict)
            completion(user)
        }
    }
}
```

Where REF_USERS it's the reference of all users in the Firebase-Database

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is this `Api.User.`? You can access the currently authenticated user anywhere in your app with this code `let user = Auth.auth().currentUser` - can you clarify what you're asking? Also, please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Jay: basically Api.User is a class created by be that contains a method (observeCurrentuser) that retrieves the user and pass it as an argument of the closure.

Comment: ...and...? Can you clarify what the question is and why that's needed? What's the actual issue?

Comment: The problem is that when I try to print the currentuser inside the closure it exists, but when I try to do this outside it it doesn't. How can I set the var self.user (that is a the view controller's variable) with the user retrieved in the closure?

Comment: Do what you have to do inside the closure in `fetchUser` or – more cumbersome – add a completion handler.

Comment: What you are doing is correct and it works when I copy and paste the code. However, the question is still unclear - you're not showing *where* you are trying to use the *user* var outside the closure. In other words, if you `print(self.user)` on the line following `fetchUser()`, it won't print anything because the *user* var will only become valid inside the observeCurrentUser closure. However, if you have a button the user clicks that `print(self.user)` then it will work (at least it works for me). There's not enough code to understand the use case.

Comment: Ok I understand where I missed giving you information sorry for the bad explanation : the steps I want to accomplish are: 
1) retrieve the user and set the self.user equal to it
2) once the var user (of the VC) is set I want to extract some data contained in the user object and set some UI of the VC such as labels and UIImageViews using user datas. 
The problem is that I cannot use the self.user because outside the brackets of the closure 'observeCurrentUser' is not set at all and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You can add a method `configureContent()` where you will update UI in the way you want and call it inside the closure after `self.user = user`.

Comment: I created the function suggested by you @ValentinaKonatar, but when I execute the code I have this error code : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Could you provide the code where that error happened?

Comment: @ValentinaKonatar I edited my question with the snapshot of my code.

Comment: Pease don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers.

Comment: It's still incomplete code. We don't know what `Api.User.observeCurrentUser` does and why it's setting *user* to nil. Please review the above links about how to ask good questions, how to include  a complete example and also why not to post images in your question. After you read that, update your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: I took out links and photos and substitute it with actual code. Hope it's alright @Jay

Answer (score 1):

Outside the closure, the observe request hasn't completed. The correct approach is to do everything that you need to do with the retrieved user -- including updating the UI -- *inside* the closure.

```
func fetchUser(){
    Api.User.observeCurrentUser { (user) in
        self.user = user
        // alternatively, add this line to the user setter.  but for now...
        self.updateUIBecauseTheUserChanged()
    }
}

func updateUIBecauseTheUserChanged() {
    // change the UI, e.g. reloadData on the collection view
}
```

Comment: I did what you said creating this function:
`func updateUIuserChanged(with user : User){
        self.userNameLabel.text = user.username
    }` and then passing the user data inside of the closure. but when I run the app it prints out this error : `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks everyone for the support. I implemented what you suggested me and it worked well. thanks